# Composable Component does not re-render after updating mutable value (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: java, kotlin, rendering, android-jetpack, state-management

In Jetpack Compose Desktop the following code renders a 4 rows and 4 columns of text fields with a number as value.
I want to trigger re-rendering on user input from keyboard. When debugging the code gets inside the body of the onKeyEvent and updates the mutable variable gameBoardBox. I would expect that the playingBoard method gets called again and rerendered, however, it does not happen, even though the I see that the gameBoardBox variable` s values were updated.
How could I trigger rerender in my case?
The gameboard is an object with an array of intarrays as property.

Following the example [in docs](https://www.jetpackcompose.net/state-in-jetpack-compose) does not bring desired results

```
    @Composable
    fun tile(color: Color, value: Int) =
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(Dp(100F), Dp(100F)).border(Dp(2f), Color.Black).background(color)) {
            Text(
                value.toString(),
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun playingBoard() = Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(100, 100, 100)),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        var gameBoardBox by remember { mutableStateOf(gameBoard) }

        Row(Modifier.focusable()
            .onKeyEvent {

                if (it.key == Key.K) {
                    movementService.shift(Direction.RIGHT) // this line makes a new object of gameBoard, so the variable gets updated
                    gameBoardBox = gameBoard 
                    true
                }
                println("hi")
                false

            }) {
            repeat(4) { column ->
                Column {
                    repeat(4) { row ->
                        Row {
                            tile(Color.Gray, gameBoardBox.playingArea[row][column])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to avoid using mutable objects as state. So instead of an array of arrays use `mutableStateListOf<List<Int>>`

Comment: @bylazy ok but why though

Comment: As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state): Using mutable objects such as ArrayList<T> or mutableListOf() as state in Compose causes your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app. Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, are not observable by Compose and don't trigger a recomposition when they change. Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, the recommendation is to use an observable data holder such as State<List<T>> and the immutable listOf().

Comment: @bylazy though you are correct, that would require a vast change on existing architecture.
I was able to solve it by initialising as:
        var gameBoardBox: MutableState<Array<IntArray>> = mutableStateOf(gameBoard.playingArea)

and updating the value like this:
                    gameBoardBox.value = gameBoard.playingArea

the window gets rerendered once I started using an array of integer arrays and not custom GameBoard object.